# Interest rate compounded continuously (pre-calculus)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

(a) Suppose you deposit $P$ dollars into a bank that pays an interest rate $r$ compounded continuously. How long does it take to double your original deposit $P$.

(b) Suppose you deposit $P$ dollars into a bank that compounds interest continuously. What is the interest rate $r$ that doubles your original investment $P$ after the first year.

The equation for continuous compound interest is $A = Pe^{rt}$ where $P$ = principal value, $r$ = interest rate per year, $t$ = time in years, $A$ = amount, and $e$ = the mathematical constant $e$

I've been working on this question for hours now, but I don't know if the answers I got are correct so I would appreciate some confirmation

The answer I got for a. is $t = (\ln2A/P)/r$

The answer I got for b. is $r = (\ln2A/P)/t$

Comment: The amount A is just 2P for case (a). You're solving Pe^(rt) = 2P so t = (ln 2)/r.

Comment: Indeed, you should start by setting $A = 2P$ to represent doubling your investment.  Then $A/P$ simplifies to just $2$.  You should also learn how to format your questions so that they are more readable.

Comment: Presumably in (b) you have $t=1$

Answer (score 0):

EDIT1:

a. *Time to double the principal P:*

The results  you obtained after *infinitesimal time compounding* in exponential form is correct. Now after cancelling $(A,P)$ magnitudes its quotient is 2,

$$e^{rt}=\dfrac{A}{P} =2$$

or simply (you need to plug in A/P value!)

$$ rt =\ln2,\, t=\dfrac {\ln 2}{r}  $$

b. *Humongous interest rate to double the principal in one year itself*

Now doubling the principal in one year needs an exorbitant charging (so least it deserves is representation with a capital $R$!)

$$ e^{\,1\cdot R}= \dfrac{A}{P}= 2 \rightarrow R = ln\,2 \approx 0.69315 $$
so the rate  of interest would be a whopping

$$ R \approx 69.315\text{ % }.$$

Comment: In question a) the question is time, not interest rate, so in the last step you need t = ..., not r = ... .

Comment: Thanks, fixed it,